# Can I selectively run db:schema:load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rake

I have a script that is going to be run on boot of a virtual instance containing a Rails app. This is part of an automated system for setting up test environments, so I'd like it to initialize correctly whether or not this is the first time the app has been launched in this environment. That is, the first time the environment sees this app, it should run the standard:

```
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
rake db:fixtures:load
```

But any time after the DB has already been created, it should just ignore those commands. So far, it's smart enough to know that db:create can be skipped, but it keeps re-running the others.

Is there an easy way to handle this besides making a direct call to the DB and acting on that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the pragmatic solution would be to ignore the error on db:create (if the db exists, it will raise an exception)

So you can create a rake task like

```
task :my_task => :environment do
  begin
    Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:schema:load"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:fixtures:load"].invoke
  rescue Exception => e
  end

  #more stuff...
end
```